# Swift Optionals which to choose

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

In swift, when making a variable optional, when would you want to use ! over ? or vice versa. I understand the difference between them, but are there some scenarios where one would not be appropriate and the other would?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only use an implicitly unwrapped optional (`!`) if you are absolutely sure that its value will be set to something other than `nil` when you go to use it. If you try to access the value of an implicitly unwrapped optional when it's set to `nil`, it will trigger a runtime crash.

For example, this will compile:

```
var a: Int! = nil
var b = a + 1
```

But, it will crash when you try to call `a + 1`.

However, if you use a standard optional (`?`), it will tell you at compile time that you made an error and catch your potential crash before it happens:

```
var a: Int? = nil
var b = a + 1 // Compile error here
```

You can, of course, check for `nil` in both cases but, if you need to check for `nil` anyway, why not just use the safer standard optional and catch any checks you may have missed at compile time instead of crashing at some unknown point in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I was just doing some testing in playground and it seems that `println()` will show nil for a implicitly unwrapped optional and does not show any compile time errors, but will error if you use a standard optional and then unwrap it, which is what confused me about which to use. I was only testing with `String` so wasn't doing anything with the variable. Thanks for clarifying this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly unwrapped optionals (those declared with `!`) can be used when you know the value will never be `nil` (because you test for that case and handle it) but need to have an optional for some reason. I use these to capture the results of Cocoa methods that return optionals, check them immediately and handle the error case, and then can use them without an unwrapping operator.

```
let myData: NSData! = NSDate(contentsOfFile: filePath)
if myData == nil {
    // handle error reporting, etc
}
```

Regular optionals (declared with `?`) should basically be used everywhere else you truly need an optional value -- you lose the safety that optionals provide otherwise.

```
let myInt: Int? = myString.toInt()
```

Of course, with the addition of the null coalescing operator (`??`), there are lots of times when you simply don't need an optional at all.

```
let myInt: Int = myString.toInt() ?? 0
```

Comment: Implicitly unwrapped optionals are not there for convenience, at times were you will check it anyway. Use Optionals then. The main reasen for the `!` operator is because you are forced to initialize every property in the init-method. That isn't possible with storyboard elements, so it is set shortly after the init-method, but then it is never nil. Described in the Swift iBook.